# How to record a video using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming

I found a code in the google that I can enable my webcam, but I would like to write a function that record the video and save in my directory server automatically when I stop it.
My code:

index.html

```
<head>
    <title>CAM</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body onload="main()">
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>    
    <button id ="record">Record</button>
    <button id ="stop">Stop</button>
</body>
```

Script.js

```
let VIDEO = null;
let CONTEXT = null;

function main(){
    CANVAS = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    CONTEXT = CANVAS.getContext("2d");
    CANVAS.width = window.innerWidth;
    CANVAS.height = window.innerHeight;


    let promise = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true});
    promise.then(function(signal){
        VIDEO = document.createElement("video");
        VIDEO.srcObject = signal;
        VIDEO.play();

        VIDEO.onloadeddata = function(){
            updateCanvas();
        }
    }).catch(function(err){
        alert("Camera error: "+err);
    })
}

function updateCanvas(){
    CONTEXT.drawImage(VIDEO, 0, 0);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(updateCanvas);
}
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Canvas doesn't really help you here.  Take a look at the MediaRecorder API.

Comment: I've test this MediaRecorder API, but it doesn't working in mobiles browser only desktop

Comment: This is not true... the MediaRecorder API works fine on mobile.

Comment: Can you send a example of code?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder#example